# How do you list down a python dependency that depends on itself?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have seen a few packages on github that does something like this:

`from setuptools import setup, find_packages`

`import mypackage`

`setup(name="mypackage", version=mypackage.__version__ ..`

This would fail as mypackage when running "python setup.py develop" as mypackage has not been installed yet. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No it wouldn't. If you have 2 files in the same directory, they can import each other.

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` and `mypackage.py` are in the same directory, so when you run `python setup.py develop`, `mypackage` is being imported from the local directory, not from one of the standard locations where (presumably) `mypackage` will eventually be installed.

You could verify this, if you like, by adding

```
print my package.__file__
```

following the `import` statement and observing the local path that is printed.

Comment: Ah, actually I see the problem now is that the package itself depends on other dependencies that have not been installed, so when it calls "import mypackage" it fails.